How to generate transition texture
I have two cubes with their own material with texture image perspectively. Now I join them, bridge their edges, and get some new faces. I want to give the new faces material to make the whole look nice. The target is to be like this:
I think I can use shader nodes, sample the texture with uv coordinate, and mix it whith color ramp, but dont have any idea on implementing the sample step.
I have read how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials and other similar questions. They give inspirations but their textures are all with regular color. If my cubes are like, the transition wont be good.
For the colorful cubes, I want the point to point transtion.
What I am trying to do finally is that, I join an arm to a body from different characters and get additional transition mesh. I want to give the new generated mesh a new material with texture to make the connection part more natual. To be specific, 'more natual' means from one color to another color like it is in figure 1. I think I can use Bilinear Interpolation or Spline Interpolation and other theory, but dont know how to achieve it procedurally

tbh i cannot see where your one texture starts and where the other ones end...maybe my eyes are bad...so what do you want to smooth out here!? i think you should at least add two pictures of your textures so we know what you are talking about.

..Yup ... please share your shader node-tree, with some indication of how you want the transition to look.. do you want a blend, or hard shapes becoming smaller/less frequent?

@Chris,@RobinBetts , I have provided more information. Thanks

I understood your question, but from given info we can't tell what is wrong with your setup or how to setup transition node-tree if we dont know what ideal transition should looks like  for you. Simplified blend with textures could be helpful (use blend-exchange.com) ... if you need just a new material for newly generated faces go t Material propertis add a new one and Assign.

Instead if transition I would say you need to create another UVmap of entire body and  bake your two textures onto a single texture based on lastly generated UVmap ... Like here https://youtu.be/WNAQgQGRmgQ?si=fv_ysKiwLE7N1yj_   and then manually paint missing part into a baked texture.

If you have two different UV maps ...

... and create a connection new faces are crated and those needs position on both UVmaps as well. Once you set them you have to merge original materials into one and then specify a way of transition between those shaders. Here I used simple X axis to be a Factor for mixing.


Mixed textures ... for two totally different images it will look not seamless ...



... but I gues you will try to create some kind of texture or adjust UV that will match better for seamless result. Like here are two images but with the same UVmap and textures are similar structure, so they looks seamless.


That's exactly how my demo runs. The question is that it works  when original materials are all in single color. But if they have their own special textures, the transition part may not look nice

It all depends on UVmaps and textures how they are set for sure :) From your real case I'm not sure how desired result should look like OK for you.
